# Usage of "See you there"

Tags: word-usage

Is it appropriate to say *See you there* if I won't be there myself?

For example, I say to my colleague:

> See you at the concert!

I won't be at this concert, but I can watch it on TV and so see the colleague.

Or I'm saying to my friend:

> See you on the football field!

I won't play,  but I will be on stands watching my friend.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use it in this context. The natural response would be—"O, you're coming to the game?" etc.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the first scenario, when you say "see you there" when addressing an audience member at a concert, the usual implication is that you'll be coming along for the same event and joining him/her in the audience (in immediate or close proximity). If all you're doing is watching the event on TV, a better expression would be *"Hope to catch you on TV!"* or something to that effect.

With regard to the second scenario, it's fine (as David's answer has stated). As a spectator at the game, you will definitely be seeing your friend on the pitch. The situation would be different if your friend were also a spectator, but you were only able to watch the game on live TV, in which case, the answer would be the same as what I've given for the first scenario.